# Can I use the Youtube API to write comments?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Can I use the Youtube API to write comments? If yes, please provide an example request.

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation, there are two endpoints that you can use: [Comments](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/insert) and [CommentThreads](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert), depending on whether your comment is a reply to an existing one, or, otherwise, is a top-level comment (i.e. one that starts a new thread). The reference docs also provide examples attached.